# Strange jQuery behavior in Mac and Win

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have simple click on checkbox

```
jQuery('#some_div .checkbox').click(function(){
    console.log(jQuery(this));
    console.log(jQuery(this).val());
    //....
<input type="checkbox" value="15" class="checkbox" >
```

But on windows this does not work.

Mac FireFox 17.0.1
[image: mac]

Win FireFox 17.0.1
[image: win]

Same in IE. Chrome works fine.

Comment: What is your html? Where's this 11 value come from?

Comment: @kidwon `console.log(jQuery(this).val());`

Comment: @Kirix I dont usually have problems with jQuery not functioning properly across OS' on the same browser. Could you please post up expanded HTML and jQuery. Thanks

Comment: @Kirix I can see that. My point was what the checkbox looks like in your HTML markup

Comment: @kidwon `<input type="checkbox" value="15" class="checkbox" >`

Comment: The value of the checkbox in your example is `15`. So where does the `11` come from? There must be some other interfering with that part you have pasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you're not using the proper event listener.
You should use `.select()` instead of `.click()`.

Comment: event fires, but value is not as it should be.

Comment: Then please show us what's the checkbox look like so that we could trace the problem if you insist on helping you

Comment: Well I'm with FF 12.0 on WinXP and the value prints just fine in browser's console with your code.

Comment: i see, but in joomla it doesn't work... May be because mootolos, but i am using noConflict

Comment: That is strange... maybe `jQuery(this).attr('value')` would make it

Comment: no luck, but now with `attr` or `val` it always returns the value of last checbox.

Comment: What `jQuery('#some_div .checkbox').length` says or `console.log(jQuery('#some_div .checkbox')[0])` see if the targeted checkbox is selected  ?

Comment: here is some test from console https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14396564/screens/Untitled.png