# Strange jQuery behavior in Mac and Win after small research

Tags: javascript, jquery

After [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972046/strange-jquery-behavior-in-mac-and-win) i found a strange bug in jQuery or in Firefox. Can you explain which of it is right.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    //Works on Windows in: Firefox(17.0.1), IE
    //Doesn't work on OS X 10.8 in: Firefox(17.0.1), Safari
    //And also doesn't work on Windows in Chrome
    jQuery('input').focus(function(){
        jQuery(this).val('');
    });

    //Same on events: change, click, select, on
    jQuery('.checkbox').click(function(){ 
        alert(jQuery(this).val());
    });
});​
```

Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/nonamez/Gq8VK/

Comment: Actually it does work: http://jsfiddle.net/Gq8VK/3/ What do you mean by "not working"? Where do you assume a problem?

Comment: Clicking a checkbox doesn't give it focus. This is working exactly how it should. Use tab to tab through the checkboxes then click them.

Comment: Checking and unchecking the box won't change the value of it.

Comment: @Jack on windows it does in ff it does

Comment: @Shmiddty wich browser and operating system do you use?

Comment: See this demo. The outline of the checkbox will turn red when it is focused: http://jsfiddle.net/Gq8VK/4/

Comment: @feeela on windows focus works and clears value, on mac not.

Comment: @Kirix Then you have found a bug. Are you aware that the selected status (the visible checkmark) is not the value?

Comment: @Shmiddty can you try my example on windows from FF?

Comment: @feeela it should return value which is a number, but it returns empty string because focus works.

Comment: @Kirix Would you please re-read my question and give a useful answer? Your current answer has nothing to do with my question… Your example does not match your error – thus there must be some more code to reproduce that error!

Comment: I'm trying to track down in the W3 spec where it defines what should happen when a checkbox is clicked.

Comment: @feeela What information do you need??? On my macbook with OS X 10.8 in Firefox 17.0.1 on checkbox click returns its value, the same script on Windows in same Firefox 17.0.1 on same click returns empty string because focus also works.

Comment: This isn't necessarily a bug. If the w3 doesn't define whether or not the checkbox should be focused as a result of a click event, that is left up to the browser to determine.

Comment: @Kirix A question of course. And a description of what you think is wrong. Because currently there is nothing wrong in you jsfiddle example.

Comment: @feeela Result in fiddle depends on operating system. In ff on windows it is empty, but on mac in SAME FIREFOX VERSION it returns a value. Also empty in IE. WebKit returns value. So behavior of .focus is different in some situations and as a result can not rely on it. So where is the bug? Is it clear enought?

Comment: @Kirix, please don't use comments to explain your poorly written OP.  _Improve_ your question by using the "edit" link, or you're likely to continue getting down-votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all browsers have the same behavior when it comes to form elements. What you are seeing is that webkit browsers aren't causing the checkbox to be focused as a result of the click event. Whether or not this is a bug would be decided by the w3 spec.

I can't find a definitive answer at w3.org on the subject. Most of what I've found seems to suggest that this is left up to the user agent.

You can, however, make all browsers behave the same by including this in your scripts: http://jsfiddle.net/Gq8VK/5/

```
// Any input that does not receive focus from a mouseclick 
// will now do so, in all browsers. This shouldn't affect browsers that
// focus input elements on click. 
$(document).on('mouseup', 'input', function(){
    if (!$(this).is(":focus")) $(this).focus();
});
```

The script is using event delegation, so it will work for all inputs including ones that don't exist in the DOM when the event is attached.

Answer (score 1):

Well Firefox is doing what it is suppose to, on focus it sets the value to blank the runs the click callback that alerts you the bank value you just set. 
In Webkit based browsers you can to include a "tabindex" attribute on the elements and use that to check for focus. Webkit doesn't work when you use the mouse to fire the focus event, it seems to work fine for inputs and textareas.

Comment: Actually Webkit **does** support focus on checkboxes – you just can't focus them using the mouse.

Comment: Incorrect. You can focus checkboxes by tabbing through the document.

Comment: But as i said, it works different in same fireboxes on different systems.

Comment: @Kirix Yeah it does – as so many web-related features are working differently across different browsers and OS. That's still not a question.

Comment: @feeela you are right, i'll edit my answer